# Running multiple instances of JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I'm running two instances of JHipster. Each have its server port different. What do I else need to change to make the grunt serve and other stuff to work ?

Comment: What problems are you running into currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the ports for gulp browser-sync 3000 and browser-sync ui 3001 and spring-boot 8080.
It means that:

- in application-dev.yml, you must change server.port from 8080 to another value (e.g 8081)
- in Gruntfile.js, you must set [browser-sync server](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-server) to use another port (e.g 3002 not 3001 as it is used for BS UI) and also change [browser-sync ui port](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-ui) (e.g 3003) . You must also change the proxy port to what you set in application-dev.yml

Comment: Thank you Gaël :) I can now run multiple instances :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) You should also consider moving from grunt to gulp as this is what the JHipster team is doing right now.

Comment: Just curious. Why Gulp over Grunt ?

Comment: Full discussion is here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jhipster-dev/pSQXz_NWcZ0